# What does the name of the singer "约瑟翰 庞麦郎" mean?

Tags: meaning

I did a quick search and have found:

> 姓名： 约瑟翰 庞麦郎 英文名: Joseeh Punmanlon

I know it is supposed to be like "Snoop Dogg," "Buddy Guy" or something like that. But I'm still very curious on if that would have any meaning or cultural reference? Something a non-native Chinese wouldn't understand?

And what about the "English name" part, is that just a loose transliteration? If that's the case I'd think "Yosehan Pamelo" to be a better alternative, very "mid-aged-Brooklyn-mafia-member-ish"....

Comment: 约瑟翰 looks and sounds *very* Biblical. 约瑟 means Joseph and 翰 is very reminiscent of John (约翰) : I would translate it as Johnseph (but you can see how Joseeh came about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, it is Joe the big wheatman!

Joking aside, Pang Mailang seems to be his real name, while Yuesehan is more like an artistic nickname, like "Joseph".

Comment: "artistic nickname" you mean like stage name?

Comment: In one of his interviews he said 庞麦郎 is just part of his stage name. He said he chose this name because he want to "释放自己", but he didn't state how. Judging by how he talks he doesn't seem to possess the ability to come out with a meaningful English name.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mean anything.

There is a rule for English-Chinese name translation. You can google it.

Some names might vary from places like Taiwan, Hongkong, etc.

e.g. **Madonna** is **麦当娜** in mainland, **玛丹娜** in Tawiwan and Hongkong.

Comment: But this guy is a Chinese singer, how can his name be an translation from English to Chinese and not the other way around?

Comment: His Chinese name is 庞麦郎 while he named himself 约瑟翰 庞麦郎 as an international name.
About his Chinese name, I don't see any evident sense. 麦郎 is not a word.@nicobili

Comment: When translating Chinese names to English, there are usually two ways: 1.Hongkong-style spelling. 2.Pingyin. But there is an additional way some people might take, which is to spell in a Western style(similar pronounciation). My name is 玄/Xuan and I named myself Sean, in the 3rd way. My surname is 张/Zhang and In english I write Cheung, Which is in Hongkong Style.@nicobili

Comment: Thank you but I'm still quite confused. So are you saying that basically his Chinese name is straight nonsense, which makes the English characters transliterated also nonsense?

Comment: @nicobili yes. Not all Chinese names make sense.

Comment: If I were you I'd just use "Zhang". I think it looks very exotic because "zh" is quite Russian-ish. And that does place you among the last when teacher takes attendance, and gives you a little bit more time before the teacher mark you as absent or late... LOL

Comment: @nicobili LOL yep you are right. I just want it to be easy to pronounce for people who don't know Chinese much. I've no idea about the Russian part :D

Comment: by "Russian-ish" I mean names like Red Army's Georgiy Zhukov (朱可夫).. I think when they made Pinyin they probably thought about compatibility issues with the Soviet.

Comment: @nicobili I know what you mean. By the way, Russian names usually end with -sky(male) -a(female) :)

Comment: "Madonna" IS "麥當娜" in Hong Kong; the pronunciation of "麥當娜" in Cantonese matches "Madonna" perfectly.

Comment: @HenryHO That is what HK uses nowadays. HK and mainland are getting closer, therefore HK's young people speak Mandarin better than before. Also see : 荷里活Hollywood好莱坞. 碧咸Beckham贝克汉姆.

Comment: @Sean  No, that's a lie.  "Madonna" == "麥當娜" in HK for 30+ years.  And both "荷里活" and "碧咸" in Cantonese sound closer to their English original than "好莱坞" and "贝克汉姆" in Mandarin.  "贝克汉姆" is esp. a nightmare; there is no character ending in "m" in Mandarin and so they always put "姆" to simulate the sound.  How could "/ˈbɛkəm/" get translated to four vowels?!

Comment: Say 贝克汉姆 fast as you can, you'll get beckham. 碧咸 looks like some sort of food or brand mark other than a Human name. I don't like most HK versioned foreign movie name translation. Most of them are stupid. Just personal opinion. :D @HenryHO

Comment: You cannot reduce "姆" to a bare "lip closing action" no matter how fast you speak.  :D

As for translation of movie names, there are many comparison articles on the web.  I can only say that HK's version sounds more lively.  ;P

Comment: We don't pronounce each word the way they teach foreigners to do. Actually I like Cantonese more than Madarin. It's closer to Ancient Chinese and western languages. As to the name translation part, Madarin picks meaningless words to avoid confusing people. But Cantonese focuses on pronunciation more.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda like his name after you give the mixed messages to it.

But I think he just a 逗逼。Just check his lyrics, it just sh--.He become pop because of funny, nothing with music.